# Unity, why so many prefabs are getting generated?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

The code is here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] animalprefabs;
    public float spawninterval = 2.5f;
    public float spawnDelay = 2.0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

         InvokeRepeating("spawnRandomAnimal",spawnDelay, spawninterval);
        
    }

    void spawnRandomAnimal()
    {
        int animalIndex = Random.Range(0, animalprefabs.Length);
        int SpawnIndex = 20;
        Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(-SpawnIndex, SpawnIndex), 0, 25);
        Instantiate(animalprefabs[animalIndex], spawnPosition ,animalprefabs[animalIndex].transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

I want to instantiate the prefab after certain time interval randomly but somehow tonnes of prefabs are getting generated .I want one prefab to be instantiated at a random place after the time interval ... Someone plzzzz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are re-calling `invokeRepeating` every single time `Update()` is called. Everytime it gets called it adds another task to repeat.

Move it to start to fix your issue.

```
void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("spawnRandomAnimal",spawnDelay, spawninterval);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using invokerepeating() function in update(). that's why too many prefabs are generated. remove invokerepeating() from update() and try it in start() or onenable().